# Minimum value of $\frac{a^3}{c}+\frac{b^3}{d}$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c,d>0$ and $(a^2+b^2)^3=(c^2+d^2),$ Then prove that $$\frac{a^3}{c}+\frac{b^3}{d}\geq 1$$ (without using Holder Inequality)

$\bf{My\; Try::}$

Let $a=r\cos \alpha$ and $b=r\sin \alpha$ and $c=s\cos \beta$ and $d=s\sin \beta$

So we get $r^6=s^2\Rightarrow r^3=s$

Now $$\frac{r^3\cos^3 \alpha}{s\cos \beta}+\frac{r^3\sin^3 \alpha}{s\sin \beta} = \frac{r^3}{s}\left[\frac{\cos^4 \alpha}{\cos \alpha\cos \beta}+\frac{\sin^4 \alpha}{\sin \alpha\sin \beta}\right]$$
Using Cauchy Schwarz Inequality
$$ \frac{r^3}{s}\left[\frac{\cos^4 \alpha}{\cos \alpha\cos \beta}+\frac{\sin^4 \alpha}{\sin \alpha\sin \beta}\right]\geq \frac{r^3}{s}\cdot \frac{\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \alpha }{\cos \alpha\cos \beta+\sin \alpha\sin \beta}$$

So we get $$\frac{r^3\cos^3 \alpha}{s\cos \beta}+\frac{r^3\sin^3 \alpha}{s\sin \beta}\geq \frac{r^3}{s}\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(\alpha-\beta)}\geq \frac{r^3}{s}=1$$

and equality hold when $\alpha = \beta$

Is my solution is Right, If not Then how can i solve it, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Can you justify the step in which you introduced the inequality?

Comment: I think your solution is true and very nice, but Holder is better.

Comment: How is Cauchy-Schwarz applied to get that inequality?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I agree. Why deny the use of a tool so basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{a^3}{c} + \frac{b^3}{d} &= \frac{a^4}{ac} + \frac{b^4}{bd} \\
&\ge \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{ac+bd}\\
&\ge \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(a^2+b^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} (b^2+d^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Simplification**

Let $\gamma^6=(a^2+b^2)^3=c^2+d^2$. Dividing $a$ and $b$ by $\gamma$ and dividing $c$ and $d$ by $\gamma^3$, we can assume
$$
a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1\tag{1}
$$
without changing $\frac{a^3}{c}+\frac{b^3}{d}$.

---

**Variational Approach**

To maximize
$$
\frac{a^3}{c}+\frac{b^3}{d}\tag{2}
$$
we want to have
$$
3\frac{a^2}c\,\delta a-\frac{a^3}{c^2}\,\delta c+3\frac{b^2}d\,\delta b-\frac{b^3}{d^2}\,\delta d=0\tag{3}
$$
for all $\delta a,\delta b,\delta c,\delta d$ so that
$$
a\,\delta a+b\delta b=c\,\delta c+d\delta d=0\tag{4}
$$
Linearity says that there are $\lambda$ and $\mu$ so that
$$
3\frac{a^2}c=\lambda a\quad\text{and}\quad3\frac{b^2}d=\lambda b\tag{5}
$$
and
$$
-\frac{a^3}{c^2}=\mu c\quad\text{and}\quad-\frac{b^3}{d^2}=\mu d\tag{6}
$$
$(5)$ and $(6)$ say that
$$
\frac ac=\frac bd=\frac\lambda3=-\sqrt[3]{\mu}\tag{7}
$$
Equations $(1)$ and $(7)$ say that $\lambda=3$ and $\mu=-1$. Therefore, at the critical point,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a^3}{c}+\frac{b^3}{d}
&=a^2\frac ac+b^2\frac bd\\
&=1\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{a^3}{c}+\frac{b^3}{d}\ge1\tag{9}
$$